# Binomial Coefficient Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

I have tried to figure this out and I cannot. The professor gave us an answer of 13,536 but I do not see any way in which he got to his answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

A certain classroom has two rows of seats. The front row contains 8 seats and the back row contains 10 seats. How many ways are there to seat 15 students if a certain group of 4 or them refuses to sit in the front row?

Comment: Do you have an answer of your own? If so then what?

Comment: The instructor’s answer appears to be wrong.

Comment: It's possible the problem simply means that each student either sits in the front row or the back row, which would put an absolute upper bound of $2^{15}=32{,}768$ ways of choosing where to sit.  The limited number of seats in each row is one restriction.  And it's possible that the other restriction means that these four students refuse to be *all* be seated in the front row (but are OK as long as at least one of them sits in the back row).

Answer (score 0):

There are $10\times9\times8\times7=5040$ ways to seat those four that want to be in the first row.
Then there are 14 seats and 11 students left, and there are $14!/(14-11)!=14529715200$ ways to seat them.
The total number is the product of these two, namely 73229764608000.
This is somewhat larger than your professor's answer, though...

I assumed here that the students are identifiable, which (to me) seems to be the only reasonable interpretation since they have personal preferences.